# How can I get into Ubuntu 11.04 when there's no boot menu for it?

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I have just installed Ubuntu 11.04 along with my existing Vista and I see no boot menu for it on start up.

I Googled for it and got the answer that let me modify the grub file and then execute update-grub to solve it.

But all of this has be to done AFTER you can get into the system right?

My question is how can I even get into the Ubuntu system if there's no boot menu ? I tried pressing SHIFT during boot, but the screen then became still untill I released it and then boot into Vista.

I installed Ubuntu with USB stick, but I see no option of doing this on its menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [Ubuntu help page about this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows).  You don't have to boot into Ubuntu for this, you can do this from a live CD/live USB.  The gist is that you load it up, mount your hard disk, update grub, and that should then present you with the Grub menu the next time you start the machine.

Answer (score 1):

If you installed Ubuntu on your HD and you have never been able to boot it. (Which is implied, when you say, that you don't see the menu after the setup screen at startup)  then you should most likely install it again over the existing ubuntu partition. There is an Option in the installer to install the new ubuntu in place of the old ubuntu. It sounds like the installation of ubuntu is somehow messed up.

If you have already used the ubuntu installation, then you can try to repair grub or you backup your files with a live cd and install it anew.

Well I know it's not an elegant solution, but it is simple and pretty straightforward. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use easybcd from neosoft as the bootloader modification tool.

This will use the Windows bootloader instead of grub or grub2 as the main bootloader.  The result is that you are chainloading so after the Windows bootloader menu if you choose Ubuntu it will take you to the grub menu.  There is a way to set the timout to zero there in order to speed the bootup.  I have one PC using this methond and a different one that uses grub.  As a relative beginner I do not see much difference between these two options as far as functionality.